# Unable use Robot Framework with Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, robotframework

I have installed the Robot Framework plugin to use with Eclipse Luna, but while trying to open any robot script, i am getting the bellow errors, Is anybody know how to fix this?
I am using a Windows server 2012 machine, don't know why i am getting the MAC OS related error messages.

```
File contains MAC OS 9 line endings¹ which are not supported by Robot Framework.
    Please convert it using some appropriate tool.
    ¹) a Carriage Return character not immediately followed by a Line Feed character
```

Error Snippet:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: File contains MAC OS 9 line endings¹ which are not supported by Robot Framework.

Please convert it using some appropriate tool.

¹) a Carriage Return character not immediately followed by a Line Feed character

    at com.nitorcreations.robotframework.eclipseide.editors.RobotFrameworkTextfileEditor.ensureRFSupportedLineEndings(RobotFrameworkTextfileEditor.java:94)

    at com.nitorcreations.robotframework.eclipseide.editors.RobotFrameworkTextfileEditor.handleOpenDocument(RobotFrameworkTextfileEditor.java:81)

    at com.nitorcreations.robotframework.eclipseide.editors.RobotFrameworkTextfileEditor.doSetInput(RobotFrameworkTextfileEditor.java:60)

    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3220)

    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:466)

    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:374)

    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$13.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2157)

    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
```

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear? The script has been edited in Mac which has an line ending Robot framework cannot handle. Open the file in an editor, and change the line endings. Or use a tool to convert them. Notepad++ can change line endings automatically.

Comment: @Fredrik: Its not happening with all my scripts, with some of the scripts it happening, i am using sublime for writing/editing the robot scripts. Is sublime able to handle this error?

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message suggests -- to change the line endings of the file that is causing the problems?

Comment: I am expecting the issue is with the plugin, from eclipse log, i am getting these error message, any suggestion what is actually happening here????                                                                                                           !ENTRY com.nitorcreations.robotframework.eclipseide 4 0 2015-02-04 23:09:57.311
!MESSAGE File contains MAC OS 9 line endingsÂ¹ which are not supported by Robot Framework.

Comment: Got the solution actually, we need to use 'Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers' (32 or 64 bit as per requirement) instead of 'Eclipse IDE for Java Developers' eclipse installers, where Robot Framework plugin is working fine.